# Return xAxis category on click

Tags: highcharts

I can't seem to get the category from a Highchart returned on a click event on the chart itself. In other words, this works fine:

```
plotOptions: { 
  series: { 
    events: { 
      click: function(ev) {
        console.log(ev.point.category); // outputs category
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, what I'd like is to be able to get the category when a user clicks anywhere on the chart, not just on the point. It would look something like this

```
chart: { 
  events: {
    click: function(ev) {
      console.log(ev.xAxis[0].category); // undefined because doesn't exist - sure would be nice, tho
    }
  }
}
```

I've combed through both the event and the highcharts objects here, but without being able to find how to identify which category is associated with the x-value being returned.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. When you click somewhere on the chart, do you want to get the category of the nearest point ?

Comment: That could definitely be one way to think about it. I was thinking of it more abstractly where x values can be directly mapped onto categories (eg 1-100 = Jan, 101-200 = Feb, 201-300 = Mar), but that may not be where the solution lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get position x value and map to categories. Example:

```
click:function(e){
                alert('x: ' + categories[Math.floor(e.xAxis[0].value)]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pev5zos8/

Comment: Thank you for this, Sebastian! It looks like the answer just needs a minor modification - if you change the `floor` to a `round`, it'll return the correct value. With `floor`, it returns the category that's between the two points, which means when you click, for example, on the left side of "Feb", it'll return "Jan" and when you click on the left side of "Jan" it'll return "undefined".

Comment: All is up to you ;) Indeed round is better.

Comment: `round()` isn't just better, it has to be `round()`. Because the answer with `floor()` returns wrong category.